# How to configure pollInterval to make SvelteKit detect newly updated file versions?

Tags: configuration, version, sveltekit

SvelteKit does a great job to avoid full page reloads where possible. However, this can be an issue when the pages *should* be reloaded, for example when developers uploaded a new version of files.

SvelteKit addresses exactly this via pollInterval. Documentation is [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#version).

However, I don't see any effect setting pollInterval.

(1) As `vite` updates my local files during development, I visited my production ready test site with a browser (avoiding the effects of `vite`).

(2) Then I changed the configuration by setting `pollInterval` to `3000` ms in `svelte.config.js` like this:

```
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
        version: {
            pollInterval: 3000
        }
    }
};
```

(3) Additionally I changed content on some pages.

(4) Finally I uploaded it all (effectively overwriting the old files).

Result:

The client browser did only see the old (previous) content when browsing the routes, not the new content. Reloading the URLs did not help either. Only after restarting nodejs on the production test site the new content was present in the client's browser.

What am I missing? An example is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `export const pollInterval = 3000;` in a +layout.js file?